# React Router Constantly Returning "Unknown Object"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, jsx

Okay, I've spent three hours driving myself crazy trying to figure this out.  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but this is my first foray into React and I'm not sure exactly what the problem is.

My main app file looks like this:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import routes from './routes.jsx';
import map from 'lodash/map';

import MainLayout from './components/layouts/main-layout.jsx';

const history = createHistory();

const App = ({store}) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history} basename="/admin-panel">
            <Route component={MainLayout}>
                <Switch>
                    {map(routes, (route, name) => (
                        <Route key={name} path={route.path} exact={route.exact} component={route.component} />
                    ))}
                </Switch>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);

App.propTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default App;
```

The route is simply a JSON object that contains route info.  Example:

```
import React from 'react';

import DashboardContainer from './components/containers/dashboard-container.jsx';
import AdminUserContainer from './components/containers/admin-users-container.jsx';

export default {
    dashboard: {
        order:     1,
        path:      '/',
        exact:     true,
        name:      'Dashboard',
        icon:      'tachometer',
        component: DashboardContainer,
    },
    users:     {
        order:     2,
        path:      '/admin-users',
        name:      'Admin Users',
        icon:      'users',
        component: AdminUserContainer,
    }
};
```

(There's irrelevant stuff in the object; that's for the sidebar rendering, which also uses this object to render itself)

`dashboard-component.jsx` looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Dashboard from '../views/dashboard.jsx';

class DashboardContainer extends Component {
    render () {
        return (<Dashboard />);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = function (store) {
    return store;
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DashboardContainer);
```

And `dashboard.jsx` looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Dashboard extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <p>This is a test.</p>
        );
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

But for some reason, no matter what, the returned component is UnknownComponent.  Apparently, nothing is matching on `/admin-panel`, and I'm not sure why.  I've tried moving components around, merging the Routing stuff with MainLayout (which just contains the stuff that won't change every request, like the sidebar and the header), even tried the HashRouter instead of the BrowserRouter to see if that would do anything.  No dice.

Can someone familiar with React tell me just what it is I'm not doing right here?

Comment: which version of `react-router` are you using?

Comment: What does `./components/containers/dashboard-container.jsx` or the other one look like?

Comment: @Icepickle -  package.json says 4.0.8.

Comment: @TylerSebastian - They're both wrappers running through Redux's connect function to set up state, but at the moment they both just display a paragraph of text, because I'm trying to get the router working before I start working on individual pages.